Why isScrolling not working when using react-window?
I want to display the text "scrolling" when I am scrolling but nothing happens. It does not show the text. What I am doing wrong ?
code:
      <List
        innerElementType="ul"
        itemCount={data.length}
        itemSize={20}
        height={700}
        width={400}
      >
        {({ index, style, isScrolling }) => {
          if(isScrolling) {
           return <p style={{color: 'black'}}>scrolling</p>
          } else {
            return (
              <li style={style}>
                {data[index]}
              </li>
            );
          }
        }}
      </List>


I think you're just missing useIsScrolling prop on the List. If it is not there isScrolling is not available. You see an working example in the following Codesandbox Demo. Also mentioned in the example
